# What did Glenn Close mean with "really sublimated herself to my father"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In her Golden Globes speech she said:

> I'm thinking of my mom, who really sublimated herself to my father,
>   her whole life. And in her 80's she said to me: I feel like I haven't
>   accomplished anything.

What would be a better substitute for **sublimated**? Something more like **dedicated** or more like **subordinated**?

Comment: It wouldn't be surprising if *sublimated* were a malapropism there, and that she really should have said *subordinated*. But I could be wrong.

Comment: People have been 'misusing' Freudian language for a pretty long time now. It's wrong in a sense, but also in a completely normal, lots-of-people-do-it sense.

Comment: I just listened to the Oscar acceptance speech. It was off-the-cuff. People can be excused in those situations. Nevertheless, she used it incorrectly. Her mother was subjugated to her father. Sublimate is only: sublimate something. Not sublimate to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with SamBC that "sublimate" is a specialized psychological term that even many native speakers would have to look up to understand the exact nuance.

> **[sublimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(psychology))** (n): In psychology, sublimation is a mature type of defense mechanism, in which socially unacceptable impulses or idealizations are transformed into socially acceptable actions or behavior, possibly resulting in a long-term conversion of the initial impulse.

"Sublimation" is not quite the same thing as "subjugation" (much less "dedication", "subordination", or "suppression")  It is both more subtle, and less oppressive.  One example of sublimation is with the innate human desire to violently compete with other humans, which nowadays may be channeled into a love of sports.  This is generally considered a "healthier" response.  Essentially, sublimation redirects some adverse personal desire along lines that lead to greater social harmony.

In Close's situation, however, she is saying that her mother *chose* to devote her life to her husband (a surgeon) to such an extent that she felt she had no goals or desires of her own.  In contrast, Close is an accomplished actress known mostly for roles portraying strong and independent (albeit occasionally *homicidal*) women, so her speech was meant to encourage women to be strong and independent as well.

(Edit)  [Link to the relevant part of Close's Golden Globes speech](https://youtu.be/f9-fPOBbmhU?t=178).  While other parts of her speech are off the cuff, and she definitely appears emotional, this particular statement comes across like something she's said many times, and her use of "sublimated" is completely intentional.

Comment: I think "devoted" is the word I was looking for.

Comment: I don't think educated people need to look it up. Glen Close was speaking off the cuff, very emotional from having won the Oscar and simply made an error. That happens in those kinds of situations.

Comment: @Lambie  This is from her Golden Globes speech.   She didn't win an Oscar, at least not this year.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, ok, Golden Globes. Same difference. She was excited due to winning and misspoke. No big deal. She meant:She sublimated her own feelings and was subjugated by my father. Something like that.

Comment: @Lambie  Point is, the speech is online, you can look up the video and see whether she seems to use "sublimated" in error.  I don't get that sense at all.  Other parts of the speech seem more impromptu, but not this particular statement.

Comment: @Andrew I did look it up and thought it was an Oscar. That makes no difference in terms of the misuse. The entire speech is impromptu. You can see that by listening to it. It's no big deal and understandable given her excitement. There is actually a tear coming out of one eye....I am sure given her educational background that if asked, she would agree.

Answer (score 2):

I expect she was using it in its psychoanalytic sense, so not something that's normal everyday vocabulary (except in certain circles).

According to Freud, sublimation is the process in which emotions, drives, or desires are channelled into more 'acceptable' forms. Taking it in that sense, Glenn Close is suggesting that her mother felt it more socially acceptable for her to dedicate her whole self to her husband, rather than having a life, interests and so on of her own.

It's not really an authentic expression of Freudian ideas, but people have been creative with Freudian ideas and language pretty much since his work was translated.

Comment: You don't sublimate yourself to someone, that's certain. Individuals sublimate experiences they have.

Comment: Psychoanalytically, they sublimate experiences, drives, etc. What she said doesn't perfectly for Freudian theory, but people have being creative with Freudian language and ideas pretty much since his work was translated.

Comment: She misused the word. There's just no doubt about it. As for it not being an authentic expression of Freudian ideas: that is bosh. She meant: my mother was subjugated to my father.

Comment: The fact that you have no doubt does not mean that there is no doubt.

Comment: There is no doubt. This is a subject I know professionally. Enough said.